# How to reduce the size of the war

Tags: maven, spring-boot, tomcat8.5

I have to reduce the size of the war file so that I could deploy it to an external tomcat server. My war file is too huge (30MB) so it's not getting deployed.

Comment: Check the dependencies if you really need them ? Means take a look into your pom file and look if the given dependencies are really needed furthermore check if all the dependencies have the correct scope ? For example junit has test scope etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider copying JARs that your webapp use to Tomcat `/lib` folder (Refer [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions) for details about Tomcat class-loading behaviour).

Depending on what build tool you use , configure it to exclude packing these JARs to the WAR. For example in case of Maven , revise `pom.xml` to change the dependencies related to these JARs to the `provided` scope.